# Handling appending to abstraction of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reference

If I have a "reference" to a dataframe, there appears to be no way to append to it in pandas because neither append nor concat support the `inplace=True` parameter.

An (overly) simple example:

```
chosen_df, chosen_row = (candidate_a_df, candidate_a_row) if some_test else (candidate_b_df, candidate_b_row)
chosen_df = chosen_df.append(chosen_row)
```

Now because Python does something akin to copy reference by value, `chosen_df` will initially be a reference to whichever candidate dataframe passed `some_test`.

But the update semantics of pandas mean that the referenced dataframe is not updated by the result of the append function; a new label is created instead.  I believe, if there was the possibility to use `inplace=True` this would work, but it looks like that isn't likely to happen, given discussion here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14796

It's worth noting that with a simpler example using lists rather than dataframes does work, because the contents of lists are directly mutated by `append()`.

So my question is --- How could an updatable abstraction over N dataframes be achieved in Python?

The idiom is commonplace, useful and trivial in languages that allow references, so I'm guessing I'm missing a Pythonic trick, or thinking about the whole problem with the wrong hat on!

Obviously the pure illustrative example can be resolved by duplicating the append in the body of an `if...else` and concretely referencing each underlying dataframe in turn.  But this isn't scalable to more complex examples and it's a generic solution akin to references I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this specifically for pandas dataframes - so I'll answer my own question.

```
chosen_df, chosen_row = (candidate_a_df, candidate_a_row) if some_test else (candidate_b_df, candidate_b_row)
chosen_df.loc[max_idx+1] = chosen_row
```

The calculation of `max_idx` very much depends on the structure of `chosen_df`.  In the simplest case when it is a dataframe with a sequential index starting at 0, then you can simply use the length of the index to calculate it.

If `chosen_df` is non-sequential you'll need call `max()` on the index column rather than rely on the length of the index.

If `chosen_df` is a slice or groupby object then you'll need to calculate the index off the max parent dataframe to ensure it's truly the max across all rows.